# What are some tried-and-true combat models?

Tags: rpg

I'm thinking about starting a text-based RPG game using Javascript (Similar to a text adventure, but with a much more refined item/fighting system). I've had some experience with playing RPG games, but before I begin, I want to find out what some good "combat models" are. When I say combat model, I mean a tried-and-true system of how a player's strength and weapons affects his attack, defense, etc. There are a few points I'd like to hear some more about:

- How would I create a good attack for a player including weapons and traits?
- What about defense?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

Comment: There's no universally good system. Your core design, and how you tweak it during balance, is tied fundamentally to how you want your game to feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you've played RPGs, do you mean computer-based ones?

I ask because there are plenty of pen-and-paper systems that are complete and readable in ways existing games are not. Look into d20-based systems (a.k.a. a rule system from Wizard Of The Coast), GURPS, RoleMaster, etc.

Comment: Both computer and pen-and-paper games. I've also had some experience with creating pen-and-paper games (with some success), but none of my fighting systems were satisfactory in that they were either biased towards the player, enemy, didn't take into account the player's weapons or traits enough, or were too random, etc.

Comment: At some point, you can only learn about systems out there, and what may lead to certain biases. After a while, you must salt and pepper to taste. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try playing SMT Nocturne. It have a fairly balanced combat(if you know your way around the system that is) save for the secret and final boss fights.